# Django: python3 manage.py migrate ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

Tags: python, django

i'm a total noob in django so go easy on me..
i tried to run these commands on ubuntu terminal and gave me the same error

```
python3 manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations MyAppName
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py syncdb --all
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

and i was told that i should never edit manage.py

**update:** i manged to run the project and made some modifications on it.

Comment: Django is not (properly) installed.

Comment: Is there a reason why you switched from `python3` to `python`? It cannot find Django.

Comment: @KlausD. Django is installed successfully.. i managed to run the server and made updates on the project

Comment: @Stephen after i finished installing Django i tried to run the server for the first time ever with this command >> python manage.py runserver << but this gave me an error but when i googled it all the search said that i should use python3 in the command instead of python

Answer (score 1):

Django is not installed, use this comamnd to install it:

```
pip install django
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do a check of all modules installed using command - **pip list**

If it does not show django in the list of modules install it using - **pip install django**

If it shows django in the list then the version of django installed may not be compatible with the version of python you are using. You can try installing a compatible version of django.

Also, you can create a virtual environment and install django inside the environment.